# Can't send JSON in a Java HTTP POST request

Tags: java, http-post

I'm getting a 'Server returned HTTP response code: 500' error although I have checked what I'm sending (I even tried sending it with an online tool and it worked). The API Key and the JSON are correct. I get this error when trying to read the input stream with 'connection.getInputStream()'. Where could this be comming frome ? Did I forget something ? I am trying to implement this feature from the openrouteservice API : https://openrouteservice.org/dev/#/api-docs/v2/directions/{profile}/post

```java
    public static UPSRoute getRoute(Location start, Location end, String language) {
        if (language.equals("fr")) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = null;

            try {
                URL url = new URL("https://api.openrouteservice.org/v2/directions/foot-walking");
                String payload = "{\"coordinates\":[[" + start.getCoordinates() + "],[" + end.getCoordinates() + "]],\"language\":\"fr\"}";
                System.out.println(payload); //{"coordinates":[[1.463478,43.562038],[1.471717,43.560787]],"language":"fr"}
                byte[] postData = payload.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", API_KEY);
                connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json, application/geo+json, application/gpx+xml, img/png; charset=utf-8");
                connection.setDoOutput(true);

                try (DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream())) {
                    wr.write(postData);
                }

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream())); // Error is right here
                String inputLine;
                StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    content.append(inputLine);
                }
                in.close();
                connection.disconnect();

                jsonObject = new JSONObject(content.toString());
            } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return new UPSRoute(jsonObject);
        } else {
            return getRoute(start, end);
        }
    }
```

Here is the error :

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: https://api.openrouteservice.org/v2/directions/foot-walking/json
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1913)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1509)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:245)
    at UPSRouteService.getRoute(UPSRouteService.java:63)
    at Main.main(Main.java:5)
```

Comment: Use any rest client like Apache Http-Client, Jersey client instead of using URLCOnnection. Besides, post the structure of your json you are sending to the api call.

Comment: Look at the payload of the 500 response, it might actually explain what went wrong.

Comment: Why are you wrapping with `DataOutputStream`, when you don't use any of its methods?

Comment: The server is likely rejecting the POST because you didn't set `Content-Type` header.

Comment: `img/png; charset=utf-8` ?!?!? --- Shouldn't that be `image/png`, with `image` spelled out, and without the `charset` given that a PNG image is binary data? Specifying `charset` makes no sense for binary data.

Comment: I was following the example from the API because I couldn't get it working, you can see that they use `.header("Accept", "application/json, application/geo+json, application/gpx+xml, img/png; charset=utf-8")` in the Java example. I'm calling the `write` method of the class `DataOutputStream` in the try. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Andreas, it was just missing the line :

```java
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

It works fine now.